# Warnings when installing npm modules in project directories, but not when installing globally

Tags: node.js, npm, requirejs

I have observed this issue when installing both newsapi and RequireJS. The path to my project directory is as follow: `Users\username\project`

In my project directory, when I run `npm install newsapi --save` (installation instructions per the [newsapi site](https://newsapi.org/docs/client-libraries/node-js) or `npm install requirejs` (installation instructions per the [RequireJS site](https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#3), I get the following identical warnings:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\username\project\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\username\project\package.json'
npm WARN project No description
npm WARN project No repository field.
npm WARN project No README data
npm WARN project No license field.
```

It may be worth noting the `project\node_modules\newsapi` and `project\node_modules\requirejs` are still created and they seems to be populated as they should.

I noticed that when I install the modules globally (by running `npm install -g newsapi --save` or `npm install -g requirejs`) the installation succeeds without displaying any warnings. Why is this the case? What is happening in my project folder that might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install fhqhwhgads` will try to update the local project `package.json` but `npm install -g fhqwhgads` will install globally and so there's no `package.json` to update. So that's why you're note getting an warning with global installation.

If you want to create a `package.json` so that your dependencies can be tracked and replicated by others (or if you want to publish your code as a package), you can use `npm init`.

Comment: Does that mean that the warnings I get are not anything I need to worry about, provided that I don't care about tracking my dependencies?

Comment: Yes, although presumably you hope to one day deploy your app to a server or package it up to be installed elsewhere, and you will probably want a `package.json` then. I would strongly recommend creating a `package.json` now even if you think you will never use it.